# How to calculate Quantile 95 in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

How to calculate Quantile 95 value, using  SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala - The question is pretty clear to me. It is a very general question (not specific to any tables, values etc.)  with a very simple, general answer.

Comment: @mathguy .. i get that..but wanted the OP to know.

Answer (score 13):

With the SQL aggregate or analytic function `PERCENTILE_DISC()` (or perhaps `PERCENTILE_CONT()`). Google for your version of Oracle and the function name to find the Oracle documentation for these functions.

Here is how I can find the 95th percentile salary in the `HR.EMPLOYEES` table (`HR` is the standard HR schema that is installed with many Oracle databases):

```
select percentile_disc(0.95) within group (order by salary) as sal_95th_pctile
from   hr.employees
;

SAL_95TH_PCTILE
---------------
          13000
```

If instead I wanted to find the 95th percentile salary **in each department**, I would use the analytic version:

```
select percentile_disc(0.95) within group (order by salary) 
                             over (partition by department_id) as sal_95th_pctile
from   hr.employees
;
```

For the `HR.EMPLOYEES` table this makes little sense, since each department has only a few employees, so "95th percentile" is meaningless; but that's how you would do it when all "departments" had many values from which to compute the 95th percentile.

Comment: I don't understand where you specify the column your running the percentile on? is it literally pulling it from the order by? I suppose it makes sense as that would allow you to control the percentile and what it meant, high or low.

Comment: @TommyHolman - what does the documentation say?